# How to open file .html from code beind Web Part?

Tags: javascript, development, web-part

I am using this code to open the file however I can not open it

```
if (ddlColetilla.SelectedItem.ToString() != string.Empty) {
   nombreArchivo = paramcedula; nombreArchivo =
   string.Format("E:\\Coletillas\\{0}\\{1}.html",
   ddlColetilla.SelectedItem.ToString(), nombreArchivo); string script =
   "function f(){ window.open('" + nombreArchivo + "');
   Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key",
   script, true); }
```

Comment: Are you trying to load a file from the Users E: drive? If so, that will not work as it is considered a security breach (I could write code to grab your files)

Comment: Checked the permissions, but already solved otherwise only add a literal control                                                                                                   string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(archivo);
FrameLiteral.Text = content;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this code to solve the issue, adding a literal control to my solution

```
nombreArchivo = string.Format("E:\\FileName\\{0}.html", nombreArchivo);
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(archivo);
FrameLiteral.Text = content;
```